# Force sublime to place space after if/for

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

Visual studio can place space between `if` and `(`:
if you write `if(` it will autocorrect it to `if (` - with space. Same with `for` and `while`
Can you do such thing in sublime?

Answer (score 2):

#### You can install HTML-CSS-JS Prettify package.

Go to `Preferences > Package Settings > HTML-CSS-JS Prettify > Prettify Preferences - Default`

---

Then search for `space_before...` options to adapt to what you need.

In your case, probably you want this:

```
// Should the space before conditional statement be added, "if(true)" vs "if (true)"
"space_before_conditional": true,
```

`Ctrl + Shift + H` is the default key binding to run these customized settings.

This is my solution for this in ST3.

Comment: That should work, but isn't there a solution that does this without calling a function? Just when you type `if(`? And is this a multilanguage solution: will it work with C++ code, for example?

Comment: @Masafi I have no solution on automating this task yet. it stills requires to press `Ctrl + Shift + H`. But I tested with C++ code in ST3 and worked fine with these settings. if I discover something else, I will let you know about.

Answer (score 0):

From the menu, choose `Tools` -> `Developer` -> `New Snippet...`

It will generate a file like this (*delete comments for simplicity of explanation*):

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
Hello, ${1:this} is a ${2:snippet}.
]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>hello</tabTrigger>
    <scope>source.python</scope>
</snippet>
```

Save this file as `my_snippet.sublime-snippet`.

Now, every time you open some `.py` file, typing **hello** followed by <kbd>TAB</kbd>, it will generate line:

`Hello, this is a snippet.`

with `this` and `snippet` being editable. You can learn more about snippets at [here](http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/extensibility/snippets.html).

P.S.

The defined snippet for if statement in Javascript for example is:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
if (${1:true}) {${0:$TM_SELECTED_TEXT}}
]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>if</tabTrigger>
    <scope>source.js</scope>
    <description>if</description>
</snippet>
```

You can create your custom one, just name it differently and set trigger to be different from `if` + <kbd>TAB</kbd>